# One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running. Can it be fixed from admin panel?

Tags: indexer

I have a magento 2.4.3 running on a production server. I have the following error message in the admin panel.
[image: One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.]

Also some of the indexers shows "reindex required". I do not have the SSH access so how can I fix it from the admin panel?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two option for the indexer.

1. Update on Save
2. Update on Schedule

Update on Save : Update on save (realtime), Indexed data is updated as soon as a change is made in the Admin. (For example, the category products index is reindex after products are added to a category in the Admin.) This is the default.

Update on Schedule :The index is set to update on schedule according to a cron job, It is a preferred option.
If you have larger database then it is recommended setting your indexers to Update on Schedule.

You can set cron job via `Cpanel` or `SSH` for the indexer.

I suggest you indexer set **"Update on Schedule"** and add cron jobs.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion how the schedule should be? Daily (off peak)? Weekly?

Comment: Every 5 mints  */5 * * * * /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/bin/php /var/www/public_html/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/shopglobalservicesltd/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log

Comment: https://crontab.guru/every-1-hour